# Swift Class as [Any] for JSONSerialization.jsonObject

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Shinobicontrols with swift. I am trying to assign my class as the datasource:

```
getLandGradingData(community: (pickOption?[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)])!) { result in

            self.helper?.data = result

        }

func getLandGradingData(community:String, completionHandler:@escaping (_ result:Array<GradingData>) -> Void) {

        var returnedResults = Array<GradingData>()

        WebService().GetLandGradingData(community)
        {
            (result: Array<GradingData>) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                returnedResults = result
                completionHandler(returnedResults)

            }

        }

    }
```

`self.helper?.data` is expecting `[Any]` (var data: [Any]! { get set })

and I am getting the data via JSONSerialization.jsonObject

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! Array<GradingData>
```

But when I assign it to helper.data it does not work, but when I create this method:

```
func getTestData() -> [Any]?
    {
        return [GradingData(lot: "lot", andColumns: "andColumns", SLAIssuedFinalGrading: true, SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate: "SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate", CityApprovalIssued: true, CityCommentReceived: false, GradingRepair: "GradingRepair", CurbStopRepair: "CurbStopRepair", SplashPadDownSpout: "SplashPadDownSpout", RYCBOtherRepairs: "RYCBOtherRepairs", Comments: "Comments", columnCamera: "", DepositReceived: false), GradingData(lot: "lot", andColumns: "andColumns2", SLAIssuedFinalGrading: false, SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate: "SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate", CityApprovalIssued: false, CityCommentReceived: false, GradingRepair: "GradingRepair", CurbStopRepair: "CurbStopRepair", SplashPadDownSpout: "SplashPadDownSpout", RYCBOtherRepairs: "RYCBOtherRepairs", Comments: "Comments", columnCamera: "", DepositReceived: false)]
    }
```

and assign it to helper.data = getTestData() everything works as expected, my question how do I get JSONSerialization.jsonObject return the same structure as getTestData() ?

Comment: You will have to parse that `JSON` to a `GradingData` object.

Comment: What is the best way to do that?

Comment: @Sulthan how would I go about doing that, i've been googling it and having a hard time understanding